# Is it possible to add Open Graph metadata to a GitHub Pages site without using Jekyll locally?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a simple `index.md` page in a GitHub repo and I'm publishing it via the GitHub Pages "Minimal" theme.  I am *not* using Jekyll locally at all; I'm relying on Pages to render the Markdown to HTML.  I'd like to add some Open Graph metadata in the head to improve the SEO and sharing utility of the page.

Looking at the Minimal theme's [code](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal/blob/master/_layouts/default.html), it would appear that there's no way to add anything to the `<head>`.  Am I missing something, or are the GitHub themes limited in that way?  It seems like overkill to install Jekyll just to create a single page, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just [copy theme files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults) to the jekyll instance at root and edit them as you wish, Jekyll will use these files before looking for theme ones.

Or you can use the [jekyll-seo-tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/usage.md) plugin that will add OpenGraph metadata automatically for you based on your pages description, title, etc and is used by github-pages gem.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not running Jekyll locally at all.  I've added a /docs/index.md file to a repo on GitHub, and then relying on Pages to render the Markdown and serve it as HTML.  I've tried adding a description and logo to the _config.yml file and I don't see them appearing in the head of the rendered page.

Comment: Description should be in index.md, then specify to use the jekyll-seo-tag in config.yml

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I'd been searching for "github pages open graph metatdata" and wasn't finding anything.  Didn't think to search for SEO.  Also read how to customize CSS on this page, but didn't read far enough to the HTML section: https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/#customizing-your-jekyll-themes-html-layout

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to marcanuy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358587/4200446) above, I was able to get the Open Graph metadata added to the page.  Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create a new directory in the repo at `/docs/_layouts`.
2. Download the raw HTML of the `default.html` file from the [Minimal theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal/blob/master/_layouts/default.html), based on [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/#customizing-your-jekyll-themes-html-layout).
3. Copy that `default.html` file to `/docs/_layouts`.
4. Add this to the `_config.yml` file in `/docs` to enable the Jekyll SEO Tag to run on GitHub Pages, based on [these instructions](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/installation.md):

   ```
   gems:
     - jekyll-seo-tag
   ```
5. Edit `default.html` to include `{% seo %}` in the `<head>`, in order to trigger the SEO gem when the page is published.  I also removed the existing `<title>` tag from the Minimal template, since the  plugin inserts its own title.
6. Add `description:`, `logo:`, `author:`, etc. to the `_config.yml` file, based on the [SEO tag instructions](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/usage.md).  These could also be added to individual `.md` files, but I have just one in this case.

After pushing these changes to GitHub, the Open Graph and other metadata started appearing in the `<head>` of the rendered page.